# Why did the Magnus app resign in this game?

Tags: online-chess, carlsen, resigning

Recently on Play Magnus app, for age 29, I ended up in following position and the Magnus app resigned.

```
[FEN "rn3bnr/1ppk1ppp/p2P4/3p4/1P2P1P1/8/P1PP2P1/RNBQKBNR w KQ - 0 1"]
```

I just wanted to post & confirm if anyone can make any sense out of it or it was mostly a bug/Fluke (which is what I think)

Note: It was on iPad running an old ios(10.x)

Comment: Materially you are a queen, bishop and pawn up. This is a HUGE advantage. As such I'm struggling to see why you think this is a bug/Fluke. Black is just totally lost.

Comment: why the negative votes

Comment: Just a guess for the negative votes: the voters feel the question is not useful, perhaps because the position shown is too clearly lost for black.

Comment: As @L.ScottJohnson says almost certainly because to the eye of anybody who has played even a little bit of chess black is very clearly lost. Personally for a new contributor I think a downvote is unfair, especially without explaining why. Typically I downvote only for extremely crass violations or repeated unwillingness to learn. But maybe not everybody is as nice as I.

Comment: Just to be clear: are you playing as white or black?

Comment: Assuming you're White, what I want to know is: are you asking why the computer resigned in this position, or are you asking how the computer at such a high level managed to get down so much material when you haven't even developed any pieces yet?

Comment: I think this question makes more sense if OP is playing black.

Comment: @DM I think we all have a pretty good idea how the OP reached the above position. He started out as black and then when he reached the above position he used the option to switch sides and the engine promptly resigned. "Whooo! !Whooo! He's beaten (the) Magnus Carlsen (app)!"

Answer (score 1):

Black's position is completely hopeless. Any chess game between players of a somewhat decent level would end by resignation here. So the computer resigning here is not a malfunction but definitely an intended feature.